# Is IOTA byzantine fault tolerant?

Tags: tangle

Is there mathematical proof that IOTA is byzantine fault-tolerant?

Comment: I think this will lead you to the papers with the answers... https://blog.iota.org/simulation-study-of-fpc-5b9e8b5a6910/

Comment: Also here in the research forum: https://iota.cafe/
or in the published papers here:
https://www.iota.org/foundation/research-papers